# Filtering odd length strings from a list of strings

Tags: haskell

I am solving this problem:
*Using map, filter, and (.) (function composition operator),
define a function that examines a list of strings, keeping only those whose length is odd,
converts them to upper case letters, and concatenates the results to produce a single string.*

I know I can do this with a list comprehension but I have been explicitly instructed to use filter.
Right now, my code looks like this:

```
concatenateAndUpcaseOddLengthStrings :: [String] -> String
concatenateAndUpcaseOddLengthStrings [] = ""
concatenateAndUpcaseOddLengthStrings xs = filter (\x -> length x `mod` 2 == 1) xs
```

I receive this error:
*Couldn't match type ‘[Char]’ with ‘Char’
      Expected type: String
        Actual type: [[Char]]*

I am testing the filter function before adding the other components, but I can't get past this error.
Any ideas?

Comment: Well you forgot to concatenate the result.

Comment: Oh wow, duh. I usually try to make sure each component of my code is working before adding more complexity, so I must have glossed over this. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The reason this produces an error is because the `filter (…) xs` expression will return a *list* fo strings, not a single string. But your type signature specifies:

```
concatenateAndUpcaseOddLengthStrings :: [String] -> String
```

so it expects a `String`, not a `[String]`. You can make use of [**`concat :: [[a]] -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Prelude.html#v:concat) here to concatenate strings:

```
concatenateAndUpcaseOddLengthStrings :: [String] -> String
concatenateAndUpcaseOddLengthStrings xs = concat (filter (odd . length) xs)
```

or even shorter:

```
concatenateAndUpcaseOddLengthStrings :: [String] -> String
concatenateAndUpcaseOddLengthStrings = concat . filter (odd . length)
```

You however still need to implement the fact that it will convert the characters in the strings that are retained to their uppercase variant. I leave that as an exercise.